# trim new line at the end of html string

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML like this (it is from SharePoint rich text field):

```
<p><i>My awsome text</i></p>
<p>My awsome text in new line</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><b>My awsome text third time<b></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<P><SPAN id=ms-rterangecursor-start></SPAN><SPAN id=ms-rterangecursor-end></SPAN>&nbsp;</P>
<br>
```

I would like to remove last 5 lines (last three occurrences of "`<p>&nbsp;</p>`", line that contains "`ms-rterangecursor`" and the last "`<br>`"), but everything else must remain the same (text formatting and new lines and spaces in the middle of the text). How can I extract only the new lines at the end of my rich text with javascript?

Comment: "everything else must remain the same" - how do you expect it to remain the same..?

Comment: Do you have it as a string or dom nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# that splits the string by row then removes last 5 lines

```
var stringList = strng.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).toList(); 
return stringList.RemoveRange(StringList.Count - 5, 5);
```

Comment: Since you don't specify a language for the operation, I picked one for you

Comment: Last word in my question says "javascript"

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  Js sntax is very similar to C#.  You should be able to work something out from my example.